# How to access Internal Storage of Android in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, storage, dart-packages

In android we use `getFileDir()` and `getCacheDir()` for accessing the `Internal Storage`. I can see that there's a `path_provider` plugin that I can use but I can only figure out `getTemporaryDirectory()` which is analogous to `getCacheDir()` of android. So is there any alternative way of doing what `getFileDir()` does in Android.

**Is there any other way to do this that I'm aware of, or I'm missing something.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Flutter sources:

```
  /// Examples:
  ///
  ///  * iOS: `NSDocumentsDirectory`
  ///  * Android: The AppData directory.
  static Future<Directory> getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() async {
    return new Directory((await _pathProviderProxy.ptr.applicationDocumentsDirectory()).path);
```

Comment: ah ha nice spot :D

Comment: @Mosbah It isn't really same as `getFileDir`  because it returns path `data/data/your_app_package/files` whereas `getApplicationDocumentDirectory` returns path  `data/data/your_app_package/flutter/app_flutter`, though we can use `app_flutter` directory instead of  `files` without any issue

Comment: @Mosbah can you provide full example of your code? cause I tried your code but I neet to define ```_pathProviderProxy```

Answer (score 3):

**To get internal storage directory path**:
For Legacy Use these flutter plugin that provides external storage path and external public storage path,
**ext_storage: ^latest_ver**

```
String path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Details:https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage

**external_path:^latest_ver**,
For NullSafety external_path is a flutter plugin that provides internal, external storage path and external public storage path,

```
String path=await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Details:https://pub.dev/packages/external_path

Answer (score 0):

(This package is outdated with latest version of Flutter)

Use this dart package: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_ex#-example-tab-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider_ex/path_provider_ex.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<StorageInfo> _storageInfo = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    List<StorageInfo> storageInfo;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
    } on PlatformException {}

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _storageInfo = storageInfo;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                'Internal Storage root:\n ${(_storageInfo.length > 0) ? _storageInfo[0].rootDir : "unavailable"}\n'),
            Text(
                'Internal Storage appFilesDir:\n ${(_storageInfo.length > 0) ? _storageInfo[0].appFilesDir : "unavailable"}\n'),
            Text(
                'Internal Storage AvailableGB:\n ${(_storageInfo.length > 0) ? _storageInfo[0].availableGB : "unavailable"}\n'),
            Text(
                'SD Card root: ${(_storageInfo.length > 1) ? _storageInfo[1].rootDir : "unavailable"}\n'),
            Text(
                'SD Card appFilesDir: ${(_storageInfo.length > 1) ? _storageInfo[1].appFilesDir : "unavailable"}\n'),
            Text(
                'SD Card AvailableGB:\n ${(_storageInfo.length > 1) ? _storageInfo[1].availableGB : "unavailable"}\n'),
          ],
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `path_provider` to `pubspec.yaml`

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}

final directory = await _localPath;
```